# Using SELECT FROM WHERE in a report

Tags: ms-access, select, report

Hi & thanks for reading/helping!

I have a simple table with email addresses and domain names.  In an equally simple form I can list in a listbox the email addresses that go with each domain name using:

```
SELECT Emails.EmailAddr FROM Emails WHERE Emails.[DomainName]=Form![DomainName];
```

and it works perfectly.  However despite trying every permutation going I CANNOT make the same thing work in a report :-( even if I try saving the form as a report.  Can anybody help me understand why this doesn't work ...

```
SELECT Emails.EmailAddr FROM Emails WHERE Emails.[DomainName]=Report![DomainName];
```

If I omit the "Report!" then I get a list of all email addresses but with every other reference I get nothing at all or an error.

My forehead is bruised from banging it on the table!

Jimmy

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for referring to report controls is the following:

```
Reports!ReportName!ControlName
```

You should be able to use that in your SQL clause.

Comment: Thanks Erik!

I found that the following works finally ...

SELECT Emails.Email
FROM Emails
WHERE (((Emails.DomainName)=[Reports]![Domains]![DomainName]));

... however the results for the first record are repeated on every page and not changing as the DomainName changes.  If I filter for a specific record and click refresh a few times I get a result :-) but that'll be tedious as there are a few hundred domain names.